# video plays on local development environment but will not play on server - vb/Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, video

I have added a video to an internal web site that plays on button-click.  It works great in my development environment, but when I move it to the Test server it will not play.  When I click the button, the screen refreshes (it changes heading image, so I know it's working), but does not play the video.

I've checked `IIS` and the `MIME` type is set for `.mp4`.  I changed my `Visual Studio` settings to use `IIS Express` and it runs fine there.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Try
            Dim path As String
            Dim ProcessProperties As New ProcessStartInfo
            ProcessProperties.FileName = "wmplayer.exe"
            ProcessProperties.Arguments = (Server.MapPath("~") + "\content\videos\etic_demo_video.mp4")
            path = Server.MapPath("~")
            Process.Start(ProcessProperties)
        Catch vx
            Me.lblMessage.Text = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ErrorMessage-CannotLoadVideo")
            etic1.WriteToEventLog("welcome.aspx.btnHelpVideo_Click: " & vx.Message.ToString, Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error)
        End Try
```

Comment: That plays the video on the machine hosting the website because a SERVER-SIDE language is telling it to. Let us know if you still don't understand why it doesn't play on your machine.

Comment: The reason it plays for you in local is that your user is running the IIS Express process on your local machine and you have a session opened. So process.start make it happens. A better question would be "How do I properly play an MP4 video from my ASP.Net website"